# How to reset CSS in inline?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reset the CSS using inline method. I have tried to reset the CSS using styles on the body tag and the maincontainer class as well. However, I am not able to do the reset. 
Can anyone tell me how do I reset the CSS in inline method?

In the Embeded way, I am able to reset the CSS as

```
*{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
}
```

However, I am not able to get the same result when I am trying to do it inline.

Comment: What is your inline code? Where do you put it?

Comment: To accomplish this inline, you would need to add this to every tag, this is what the `*` selector means.

Comment: Other than adding that CSS to every single element, that doesn't work. `*` means EVERYTHING.

Comment: You can't just set some styles on a containing element and expect them to trickle down to all descendant elements. Not all styles, `margin` and `padding` included, are inherited.

Comment: @Matthew Isn't there any other easy way to get the result, other than adding this to every tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily test this by adding the margin and padding to every element. So if you have a simple page with let say only one div, you would have to add it to the all the tags like so

```
    <html style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto;">
    <body style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto;">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto;">
```

So this method is very repetitive. I'm not sure why you would do it, but there's probably a reason for it.

Comment: I am trying to do this, but no use i guess i will have to adjust the margin and padding in all the elements.